# Length of Time Before Invention is released or Patent is up

Tags: chemistry-microbiology

In reference to the patent: [US9005603](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9005603B2/en)

How long will Mayo Clinic "own" this naturally occurring Microbe? I want my mother to be able to benefit from this, however, the Mayo Clinic has had it patented since 2009. I want to know how long I need to tell my mother she must wait in pain and complications until she can benefit from this NATURALLY occurring microbe.

How long, please?

Answer (score 1):

The priority date of this patent is Oct. 30, 2009. The expiration date is 20 years from this date or Oct. 30, 2029. I checked on the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) site and there is no patent term adjustments.

As for the patent itself, what is covered is described in the claims. There is only one independent claim.

> 1. A composition comprising live Prevotella histicola, dead Prevotella histicola, or a culture supernatant of a Prevotella histicola culture,
>      wherein said composition is in the form of a pill, a tablet, or a
>      capsule.

However, it is a continuation of [US8617536](https://patents.google.com/patent/US8617536B2/en). That patent's first claim is as follows.

> 1. A method for treating an autoimmune condition in a mammal, wherein said method comprises oral administration of a composition comprising
>      live isolated Prevotella histicola or a culture supernatant of a
>      Prevotella histicola culture to said mammal, wherein said autoimmune
>      condition is multiple sclerosis or rheumatoid arthritis, and wherein
>      the severity of said autoimmune condition is reduced.

Just because Mayo has a patent, doesn't mean the treatment is effective or safe or better than other treatments. A patent by itself has no great value for Mayo, so there is a good chance the patent has been licensed to a drug development company to bring to market. Drug development is a long and expensive process so this may take some time.

Comment: It may be worth investigating whether the same composition or method are patented in other countries, as the US patent is only enforceable in the USA.